# How to get a list of files and extended attributes with powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to do something in PowerShell but I am struggling with it.

I would like to get a list of all the files in my computer that has an Extended Attribute (EA) with name: `'$KERNEL.SMARTLOCKER.ORIGINCLAIM'`.

I got some help and have a basic code, but it doesn't work, I don't think it's doing the right thing.

```
ls C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {

  $File = Get-NtFile -Path $_.FullName -Win32Path -Access ReadEa -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  if ($File) {
    $ExtendedAttributes = $File.GetEa()
    $ExtendedAttributes.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq '$Kernel.Smartlocker.OriginClaim' }

  }
}
```

I am using a non-standard PowerShell module that I found [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/1.1.33)
This module adds a provider and cmdlets to access the NT object manager namespace. It allows me to use Get-NtFile.

The `$_.Name` is displaying the file name and not the attribute, at least that's the feeling I have.
Also, I don't know how to send this to a file where I could see the filename, the file path and the ExtendedAttribute Name.

Although I am using this, I don't have any requirement to do so, I just want something that allows me to get the attribute I am looking for.

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!
Aganju

Comment: where did `Get-NtFile` come from? that aint part of standard PoSh ... [*grin*]

Comment: Also, are you comparing the entirety of `'$Kernel.Smartlocker.OriginClaim'` as-is, or you meant for `$kernel` to interpolate?

Comment: The Get-NtFile comes from here: [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/1.1.33)

And yes, it's not standard.

I am comparing the entirety of '$Kernel.Smartlocker.OriginClaim' as is.

Comment: @aganju82 - thank you for the info ... and _please_ add that info to your Question. it is very emphatically pertinent to what you are doing ... [*grin*]

Comment: @aganju82 Code looks alright. Perhaps there simply aren't any files with cached reputation EAs on disk at the moment. Verify that WDAC ISG authorization is enabled in your control policy and then try to launch an application (to trigger authorization) for which you know known-good reputation information is available from ISG, then try again

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below with a known entry "$KERNEL.PURGE.ESBCACHE" and it definitely works, suggesting Mathias' suggestion is correct to me. This will output to a file for you

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{
    try{
    (Get-NtFile -Path $_.FullName -Win32Path -Access ReadEa -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).getea().Entries |
    Where-Object Name -eq '$KERNEL.PURGE.ESBCACHE' |
    Select-Object Name, @{ Name='FilePath';  Expression = { $Script:_.DirectoryName }},  @{ Name='FileName';  Expression = { $script:_.Name }}
    }catch{}
} | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```